# Loop through specific objects and specific properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, loops, properties

I'm writing a jQuery validation plugin and would like to loop through some of the objects and access certain properties. I have some of the rules set as a property of the plugin like so:

```
num:
{
    msg: 'numbers only',   //error messege
    rule: /\bnum\b/,      //regex to find if the rule is set
    regex: /[^0-9]/       //regex for validating the field
}
```

In my main function I'm am trying to validate groups of rules. One such group is rules that use 1 regular expression. I tried putting them into arrays

```
var group=(num, alpha)
```

But from here I couldn't figure out how to loop through them In a way I can access the objects properties.

Comment: An array is constructed using square braces, **not** using parentheses, unless you use the `Array` constructor.

Comment: In javascript, and array is defined this way: `var group = [num, alpha];`

Comment: This `var group=(num, alpha)` will only assign `alpha` to the `group` variable.

Comment: lol oopsies. should have double checked the array syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Your validation group
var group = [num, alpha];

for(var i in group) {
  //Here is your object in your group array
  var rule = group[i];

  //Access properties
  rule.msg;
  rule.rule;
  rule.regex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access an object's properties:

```
for (var k in num) {
// k for the name
// num[k] for the value
}
```